# Laravel Eloquent - How to define such a relationship: Comment::language()->name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The languages table has: id, shortcode

The comments table has id, user_id, comment, language_id (foreign key)

In the Comment Model I defined Language as a hasOne Relationship

In the Language Model I defined Comments as a hasMany Relationship (this is wrong?).

In Tinker I get this error when I try to execute: $comment->language()->get():

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'languages.comment_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `languages` where `languages`.`comment_id` = 7 and `languages`.`comment_id` is not null)'
```

Why is Laravel searching in the languages table for the comment_id? It seems I misunderstand something completely.

What is the right way to do get the language shortcode? I thought $comment->language()->shortcode should work.

And what is the most efficient way to preload all the language_id and shortcode information without performing duplicate queries since this is used a lot?

Comment: The comment model should have a belongsTo relationship, not hasOne. Also, the tables should be named comments and languages, not comment and language.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel makes assumptions on your key-names in your relationship. Because you use the hasOne relationship, Laravel expects the key to be in the languages table, named comment_id.

Your Comment model should use a belongsTo relationship to Language and drop the hasOne. This way laravel makes the assumption that the foreign-key is actually in the comments table, named language_id, which is the case :).

Comment: thank you.  I got another question: $comment->language()->get() works but $comment->language()->shortcode doesn't. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: There are 2 things to consider with relationships:

1. If you use the function version of a relationship: 

    $comment->language();

you always receive the relationship itself. This way you could extend your query. Not very useful with belongsTo, but very useful with hasMany.
2. If you use the member version of a relationship: 

    $comment->language;

you talk to the object itself. Or in hasMany relationships, you get a Illuminate\Support\Collection.

With these options in mind, you can always make the best decision :)

Comment: If my answer was helpful, I would like to suggest hitting that answer button ;)

Comment: yes, that was very helpful. I am too new to upvote you (it won't register the upvote yet). But I appreciate your reply. I haven't programmed for ten years and things changed a lot.

Comment: @HansM. since you are the author of this question you can in fact mark this answer as correct by clicking the gray checkmark, giving your samaritan some well deserved reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Using the belongsTo relationship solved the problem.

Afterwards I could access it with $comment->language->shortcode;

thanks everyone!